# want text displayed instead of alert when validation occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so this might sound like a really stupid question, but I'm brand new to Javascript.

Basically, I want my page just to write the words "please fill in" next to a textbox that the user has not filled in.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Easy Budget</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>

<script>

function myFormFunction()
{
if (document.myForm.Name.value == "")
{
alert("Name must be filled in");
document.myForm.Name.focus();
return false;
}
if (document.myForm.Surname.value == "")
{
alert("Surname must be filled in");
document.myForm.Surname.focus();
return false;
}
if (document.myForm.Income.value == "")
{
alert("Income must be filled in");
document.myForm.Income.focus();
return false;
}
return (true) ;
}
</script>

</head>

<header>
</header>

<body>

<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return myFormFunction()" method="post">

 <h3>Work Out Your Budget</h3>

 <p><h4>Personal Details:</h4></p>

<p>  Name:  <input type="text" name="Name"></p>
<p>  Surname:   <input type="text" name="Surname"></p>
<p>  Income:    <input type="text" name="Income"></p>

 <p><h4>What are your monthly expenses?</h4></p>

 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Groceries">Groceries</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Car">Car</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="PublicTransport">Public Transport</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Rent">Rent</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Pets">Pets</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Drinking">Drinking</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Smoking">Smoking</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="NightsOut">Night's Out</input></p>
 <p><button type="Submit" value="Submit">Submit</Button></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the entire document, as I said it works fine but I don't want an alert to pop up everytime. 
I just want it to display next to the textbox "please fill in"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: $(document.myForm.Name).after("please fill in");

Comment: instead of getting help, I get voted down. Great. I did say it was probably a stupid question but I couldn't find anything yet

Comment: I tried the show() and hide() but can't seem to get that right and it seems like there should be something less complicated to do something so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I seem to have gotten it right now...

Here the JS

```
<script>

function myFormFunction()

{
if (document.myForm.Name.value == "")
{
var el1 = document.getElementById("name");
el1.style.display = "block";
document.myForm.Name.focus();
return false;
}
if (document.myForm.Surname.value == "")
{
var el2 = document.getElementById("surname");
el2.style.display = "block";
document.myForm.Surname.focus();
return false;
}
if (document.myForm.Income.value == "")
{
var el3 = document.getElementById("income");
el3.style.display = "block";
document.myForm.Income.focus();
return false;
}
return (true) ;
}
</script>
```

And here the modified form

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return myFormFunction()" method="post">

<h3>Work Out Your Budget</h3>

<p><h4>Personal Details:</h4></p>

<p> Name:   <input type="text" name="Name">
<div id="name" style="display:none">Please enter your name</div></p>
<p> Surname:    <input type="text" name="Surname">
<div id="surname" style="display:none">Please enter your surname</div></p>
<p> Income:     <input type="text" name="Income">
<div id="income" style="display:none">Please enter your income</div></p>

 <br>

 <p><h4>What are your monthly expenses?</h4></p>

 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Groceries">Groceries</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Car">Car</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="PublicTransport">Public Transport</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Rent">Rent</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Pets">Pets</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Drinking">Drinking</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="Smoking">Smoking</input></p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="NightsOut">Night's Out</input></p>

 <p><button type="Submit" value="Submit">Submit</Button></p>
</form>
```